# How do I format ticks in a Plotly Express Parallel Coordinates plot?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm creating a parallel coordinates plot using Plotly express, but I can't seem to format the ticks on the y-axis how I'd like. You can see in the plot below that the ticks have numbers like 900m; I just want them formatted as 0.9.

[image: plotly plot]

This seems to be coming from the `exponentformat` argument of the y-axis, based on the help string:

> exponentformat
>
> Determines a formatting rule for the tick exponents.
>               For example, consider the number 1,000,000,000. If
>               "none", it appears as 1,000,000,000. If "e", 1e+9. If
>               "E", 1E+9. If "power", 1x10^9 (with 9 in a super
>               script). If "SI", 1G. If "B", 1B.

So I've tried to change this argument using the `update_yaxes` method. However, the plot looks the same. How do I change the tick format to normal decimal numbers like 0.9 instead of 900m?

Code to reproduce the plot (using Plotly version 4.0.0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.DataFrame({c: np.random.rand(30) for c in "abcd"})
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(
    data,
    color="d",
    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Viridis,
)
fig.update_yaxes(exponentformat="none")
fig.show()
```

Comment: If you upgrade to version 4.1 do you still see the same output? I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of parallel coordinates plots in Plotly aren't configured using the `layout.yaxis` attributes, but rather in `data[].dimensions[].tickformat`, which is documented here: https://plot.ly/python/reference/#parcoords-dimensions-items-dimension-tickformat